# In Spring batch how to set throttle-limit from jobParameters

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am trying to pass throttle limit as jobParameter. Before starting the batch job i need to set no of threads and page size based on number of records need to be processed.

I am using below config. its giving error. 
`

```
<batch:step id="step2" next="step3">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="#{jobParameters['threadNumber']}">

                <batch:chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="#{jobParameters['chunkSize']}" /> 

            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>`
```

**Getting below error** 
`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.wdpr.payment.batch.BatchApp.main(BatchApp.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the schema to configure that won't work since it does't allow you to set the `ChunkOrientedTasklet` to step scoped.  You'd have to manually configure that step in order to do what you're attempting.

You'd be better off managing the throttle limit in the taskExecutor (making that step scoped).

Comment: Thanks for reply, how i can mention it at task executor level. I am using                `<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" scope="step">
  <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="#{jobParameters['threadNumber']}" />
  
 </bean>`

Comment: That should work. You'd just want to raise the `throttle-limit` on the job to be a high number so that the concurrency is controlled by the task executor and not Spring Batch.